# Match a letter unless escaped

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a letter (let's say `a`) that is not escaped with a backslash, but I want to do it without using negative lookaheads or negative lookbehinds, this is what I tried so far but it doesn't work

```
/([^\\][^a])*/.test('should be true a.'); // true
/([^\\][^a])*/.test('should be not true \\a.'); // true
```

But they both return true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you want to use negative lookbehinds?

Comment: More interestingly, why don't you want to use negative lookaheads (which javascript _does_ support)?

Comment: @JanDvorak because I want to know why the above code doesn't work, more than how to do it with lookaheads/behinds

Comment: @YatharthROCK: Because they are not supported in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test for an `'a'` which is not preceded by a `'\'` you could use

```
/(^|[^\\])a/.test( 'should be true a.' );        // true
/(^|[^\\])a/.test( 'should be not true \\a.' );  // false
```

The `(^|[^\\])` matches either the start of the string `^` or a character that is not `'\'`.

In your regex, the `[^a]` matches any character that is *not* `'a'`, and `()*` means match what is enclosed within the brackets *zero* or more times - so *any* string would test true, as any string could match the pattern zero times.